# Show the timestamp of when a post was deleted/closed in the recently deleted/closed lists

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, recently-deleted, recently-closed

This information is available already in the close/delete *tabs* (though only the 30 most recent items), but I like the [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-deleted) [lists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-closed) better because they show more information *about* the posts right in the list. And it's somewhat inconvenient to use both lists at the same time (there should be no reason to do so).

Comment: Confirmed this is complete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer to prevent bumping.)