# Throw some deleted highlights onto the New Posts by New Users page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation, new-users, 10k-tools

Trawling through the New Posts by New Users page, it would be swell if posts indicated when they have already been dealt with (read: deleted) by use of the background colour of red death as seen on posts elsewhere.

The keen [New Posts by New Users page (accessed by moderators and 10k users) is helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/increase-the-number-of-daily-spam-flags-with-reputation) in picking out the spam and junk answers and questions which float by in that window when the community blinks.

Having them highlighted as deleted would cut down on the amount of teasing that goes on when you're on a lightning round of deletes and spam/offensive flagging.

Comment: +1 There are so many things that could be done to the 10k Tools pages to assist in moderating. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51012/show-the-timestamp-of-when-a-post-was-deleted-closed-in-the-recently-deleted-clos http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52736/on-the-new-tags-page-please-differentiate-between-tags-with-0-questions-and-tag

Comment: @jon sorry about the laxness here, I tried to do all these tonight

Comment: Why does the link link to a welbog question that seems to be about something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would save me so much time.

They should also put the highlighting on the Close and Delete pages, so I don't keep going into those questions when I've already cast my vote.

Comment: Indeed it would save a lot of time. And today's winner of a checkmark to stop that Community user from bumping is...