# Show and sort "recently closed posts" list by close time, not post time

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sorting, 10k-tools, recently-closed

The 10k lists of recently closed posts and recently deleted posts have somewhat different styles:

[image: Screenshot of the Recently Closed Posts list]

[image: Screenshot of the Recently Deleted Posts list]

---

I prefer the deleted post list for two reasons:

- It shows the deletion time, not just the post creation time
- It orders by deletion time, not post creation time

Is it possible to change the recently closed posts list so it shows the close time and sorts by it? There's a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) post from six months ago about [adding this to both pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51012/show-the-timestamp-of-when-a-post-was-deleted-closed-in-the-recently-deleted-clos) in the first place; I'm not sure if there was a regression or if it's hiding somewhere on the closed page, but definitely the closed list doesn't sort correctly

Comment: Side-note: I've refreshed this post twice now, and both times I saw the red "status-completed" in the body and thought "wow, already?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build